# Webcam snapshot to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webcam

I'm trying to create some little webcam tool that let's you take snapshots with an overlay. Now I've been working with the html5 canvas and got the webcam working. But whenever I try to save the webcam snapshot it just only loads either the webcam snapshot or the overlay and never both.

I've been trying out a couple things this is the closest I could get:

```
var teaser = new Image();
teaser.src = "http://www.fillmurray.com/g/1200/1200";
teaser.onload = function() {
context.drawImage(teaser, 0, 0);
};    
context.drawImage(v, teaser, 0 , 0, w, h); // this only draws the image

// and

context.drawImage(v, 0 , 0, w, h); // this just draws the webcam snapshot
```

Does anyone know if this is even possible or if I'm just being a complete idiot? So what I want to achieve is to draw two images in 1 canvas and to let the overlay to be on top of the video.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Px8g3/

Comment: I didn't work 2 much with canvas, but isn't your code drawing an image on top of another? So you always have only 1? Or is your teaser transparent?

Comment: that teaser image is semi transparent, but i can't figure out why it won't load both images :-/

Comment: have the event handler set BEFORE setting src. have the video and the canvas with style='position:absolute'. Lastly, when saving, drawImage the image also.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i've been trying it but i'm probably doing it wrong again: http://jsfiddle.net/Px8g3/1/ T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this :

```
context.globalCompositionOperation = "source-atop"
```

before drawing (or after the 1st draw, try both)

To be more precise :

```
var teaser = new Image();
teaser.src = "http://www.fillmurray.com/g/1200/1200";
teaser.onload = function() {
context.drawImage(teaser, 0, 0);
};
//context.save(); Try with and without
context.globalCompositionOperation = "source-atop";
context.drawImage(v, 0 , 0, w, h); // Don't know what v is, but i guess it's an image
//context.restore(); Same
```

To be precise, this make the canvas to be in "source-atop" mode.
What does it means ?
It means that where the top layer (the 2nd image you draw) is transparent, it will keep the background (video) and draw it. Elsewhere, it will draw your 2nd layer

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I think this does solve the layering issue, but my main issue is that i can't get both images to pop-up in the canvas just one of them. So i can only load the webcam snapshot or i can only load the overlay which is the main issue. but i'll keep your code for future reference

Comment: The code i posted should do what you want.
Draw the video layer, then call what i told, then draw the overlay

Comment: Oh my bad i still had the teaser in the context.drawImage(v, teaser,0 , 0, w, h); Cheers! you made my day

Comment: Fine.
I added a little description of what is does, for thoses who are wondering.